# “Cultural” vs. “culture” in this context

Tags: grammaticality, difference, grammaticality-in-context

I wrote this:

> **Cultural** exchange is very important for societies in order to get benefits from each other. One form of **cultural** exchange is creating  good connections between academic institutions.

I don't know if I have to replace the bold words with “culture”.

I mean is it correct to use “cultural” in this context? or it would be more correct to use “culture”?

Answer (score 1):

'Culture exchange' means exchange of culture. Culture is a noun.

'Cultural exchange' means exchange pertaining to culture. Cultural is an adjective, and probably the better word to use, although I'm not sure there's much difference in this situation.

Comment: Also, I would reorder your first sentence as follows: Cultural exchange is very important in order for societies to benefit from each other.